# How can i identify multiple USB sound cards

Tags: linux-device-driver, alsa

I have a Linux computer with a usb hub and multiple usb sound cards.

Here is what i can see with aplay -l command:

```
aplay -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], périphérique 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Sous-périphériques: 8/8
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
  Sous-périphérique #1: subdevice #1
  Sous-périphérique #2: subdevice #2
  Sous-périphérique #3: subdevice #3
  Sous-périphérique #4: subdevice #4
  Sous-périphérique #5: subdevice #5
  Sous-périphérique #6: subdevice #6
  Sous-périphérique #7: subdevice #7
carte 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], périphérique 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 2: Device_1 [USB PnP Sound Device], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 3: Device_2 [USB PnP Sound Device], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 4: Device_3 [USB PnP Sound Device], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

So, i have 5 devices, which are identified by this names: ALSA, Device, Device_1, Device_2, Device_3

My question is: How can i be sure that Device_2 will match with the same USB sound card each time i boot my computer ?
Do you think the matching could be random when the computer starts ?
There is no unique identifier inside a sound card, so i am wondering how the kernel makes the matching.

Thanks

Comment: See "Identify two identical audio devices" on http://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev.

Comment: if i understand this is USB port identifier which is at the origin of the mapping ?

Comment: That page talks about how "to change their ID, depending on which port the device is connected."

Comment: If i do not touch anything to this configuration files, i will always have the same mapping ?Thanks

Comment: No; the cards numbers are random, depending on which device happens to answer first.

Comment: Okay so how to be sure i will have the same thing for each boot. I do not want to choose which device is the first or the second. I want to get the same matching for each boot. Thanks

Comment: That is explained in the link.

Comment: If the USB devices have unique iSerialNumber strings in their device descriptors, perhaps your local Udev rules could mach specific iSerialNumber strings to assign particular ALSA IDs to particular devices. The linked article matches on full device paths, which can be rather fragile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Device path basically defines which USB port the card is plugged into. Run `ls -la /sys/class/sound/` to list cards and their device pathes, then write new name to card's `id` attribute.(Use "device path" to rename each card.)

For example:

```
$ ls -la /sys/class/sound/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 May 27 17:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root 0 May 27 17:48 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 27 17:48 card1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 27 17:48 card2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 27 17:48 card3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/sound/card3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 27 17:48 card4 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/sound/card4
...
```

gives 4 device paths. Index might be different, but device path won't change until you plug the card into a different USB port.

Use these device paths to set new name:

```
echo -n NewName1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card*/id
echo -n NewName2 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card*/id
echo -n NewName3 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/sound/card*/id
echo -n NewName4 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/sound/card*/id
```

That will also change names in `cat /proc/asound/cards` and `aplay -l` output.

You can define rules to set those names automatically when devices are detected. For udev write to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-my-sound-cards.rules` something like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="NewName1"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="NewName2"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="NewName3"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="NewName4"
```

(don't forget to write *your* card names and device pathes there)

Then use those names to reference cards in your software, like say, "plughw:NewName4", "dmix:NewName2"...

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: i must say, you saved my life too!!! :D